# Runtime error 1004 - The command cannot be used on multiple selections

Tags: vba, excel

The code below copies data from a specific column and transfers it to another one. For example, if in **column A** I have data from **row 1 to 10** and press the button, then the values from row 1 to 10 will be transferred to i.e. **column D**. Afterwards, If I change the values in **row 5, 7 and 9 in column A** and press the button, only the values from **row 5, 7 and 9** will be transferred to **column D**. The reason why the code is like that is because the worksheet has many rows filled with values and I want to be transferred (copy) only the values that have been modified. Otherwise, it will take quite some time.

The code works, but sometimes I get the error **The commnand cannot be used on multiple selections**. I tried to have a look on the internet to fix it but I couldn't come up with any solutions. Any help will be appreciated!

**Note**: A user from this community helped me to write the code below a time ago, but I cannot find the link anymore for that.

This code is pasted in the worksheet that I am using:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim creation As Worksheet
    Set creation = ActiveSheet

    Dim copydata As Range
    Set copydata = Application.Intersect(target, creation.Range("A2:A5000", "A" & creation.Rows.Count))

    If (Not copydata Is Nothing) Then
        If (CopyDataRange Is Nothing) Then
            Set CopyDataRange = copydata
        Else
            Set CopyDataRange = Application.Union(CopyDataRange, copydata)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And this code is pasted in a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public CopyDataRange As Range

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If (Not CopyDataRange Is Nothing) Then
        CopyDataRange.Copy
        CopyDataRange.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues   ' this where I get the error
     Set CopyDataRange = Nothing

    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: yes, yes, I do. I will modify it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PasteSpecial` doesn't work on *multiple* ranges. You can loop over all parts of the range using the `Areas` property:

```
if Not CopyDataRange Is Nothing then
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In CopyDataRange.Areas
        r.Copy
        r.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues   
    Next
    set CopyDataRange = nothing
end if
```

This will work even if you don't have a multiple range, in that case it contains only one `Area` (`Areas.Count` = 1)

Comment: Thanks! The code does work and I didn't get any error. Must appreciated!

Comment: Smart `Copy-Paste` solution for non-contiguous ranges.

Comment: @FunThomas - I get the error `Run-time error 91: object variable or with block not set vba` in row `For Each r In CopyDataRange.Areas`. Why is that? Thanks

Comment: probably `CopyDataRange` is not set? I updated my answer to add the check (but you had it already in your code)